# IOS cell.textLabel.textColor doesn't change cell text color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I create a tableview programmatically

I want to change cell text color but `cell.textLabel.textColor` doesn't change the text color

```
   //create tableview
    _riskListTableView=nil;
    _riskListTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,risksMainLabel.frame.origin.y+risksMainLabel.bounds.size.height+10 , 250, 100)
                                                           style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    _riskListTableView .autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    _riskListTableView.separatorStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    _riskListTableView .delegate = self;
    _riskListTableView .dataSource = self;
    _riskListTableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [_riskListTableView reloadData];
[self.view addSubview:_riskListTableView];
```

cell setup

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    else{
//        if ([cell subviews]){
//            for (UIView *subview in [cell subviews]) {
//                [subview removeFromSuperview];
//            }
//        }
    }

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    cell.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    cell.textLabel.text=[_riskList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
    cell.textLabel.font= [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    return cell;
}
```

[image]

I can change font, or cell back ground color but can't change cell text color.
Whats going on?

Comment: Not sure of how fonts work, but maybe this is worth a try: try to set the font before changing color... and also try not setting the font to see if the text color is changing

Comment: darn `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` works `cell.userInteractionEnabled=NO;` makes cell look like disabled